# parse variable to xml

Tags: javascript, xml

I would like to parse my variable "valueStations2" into a xml string.
Instead of a static sos:FeatureOfInterestId value (here e.g. "stationname") I would like to have a dynamic parsed from javascript. 
I tried setting my variable in quotes like "valueStation2" for "stationname"
but xml does not except. 
I would like to know how to add a variable to xml. Any suggestions?

```
  var valueStation2;

  var xml = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?> 
  <sos:GetFeatureOfInterestTime     
     xmlns:sos='http://www.opengis.net/sos/1.0' 
     service='SOS' version='1.0.0' 
     xmlns:ows='http://www.opengeospatial.net/ows'> 
     <sos:FeatureOfInterestId>stationname</sos:FeatureOfInterestId> 
  </sos:GetFeatureOfInterestTime>";

// create handler
var request = OpenLayers.Request.POST({
    url: "http://139.17.3.301:8080/mydata/sos",
    data: xml,
    callback: handler
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
 var valueStation2;

 var xmlString = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?> 
 <sos:GetFeatureOfInterestTime xmlns:sos='http://www.opengis.net/sos/1.0' service='SOS' version='1.0.0' xmlns:ows='http://www.opengeospatial.net/ows'> 
      <sos:FeatureOfInterestId>" + valueStation2 + "</sos:FeatureOfInterestId> 
 </sos:GetFeatureOfInterestTime>";

 var xmlParser = new DOMParser();
 var xmlDOM = xmlParser.parseFromString(xmlString, "text/xml");
```

Wrapping any variable with quotes will turn it into a string which is not what you're looking for.

Comment: thank you, but it still does not except the valueStation2 variable as it contains a string (var variableStation2 = "station2"). The error message is                       
  <ows:Exception exceptionCode="InvalidParameterValue" locator="featureOfInterestID">
    <ows:ExceptionText>The value 'valueStation2' of the parameter 'featureOfInterestID' is invalid!</ows:ExceptionText>
  </ows:Exception>
</ows:ExceptionReport>

Comment: Your expected value of `valueStation2` is the string literal `stationname`? If you hardcoded it as a string and it doesn't work, then the origin of the problem isn't the variable but the expected value.