# Creating XML in Javascript on PHP page causes '<?' to be interpreted as PHP

Tags: javascript, php, xml

I have a form on a .php page, the contents of which I want to put inside an XML document. I'm currently doing this as such:

```
var data = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>" + 
'<request><reference>' + formfield1 + '</reference>
<location>' + formfield2   + '</location>
//etc
```

This approach is outlined in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27108216/parse-variable-to-xml).

The variables refer to inputs in the form, and as per `console.log` they correctly get the values from the form.

However, the issue I'm running into, is the `<?` and `?>` tags, which are interpreted as PHP. I've tried escaping like `\<\?`, but that results in a variable which includes the backslashes, which obviously isn't what I want.

I'm probably missing something silly, but I've searched extensively for a solution, and have not been able to find one.

**UPDATE**
Thanks to WillParky93, I came up with this code, which breaks the variable into small bits and pieces printed onto the page by PHP:

```
var data =
<?php print("'" . '<' . '?' . 'xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"' . '?' . '>' . "'"); ?>;
data += '<request><reference>' + formfield1 + '</reference>
<location>' + formfield2   + '</location>
//etc
```

This seems to have resolved the issue, and the `data` variable is now shown correctly by `console.log`

Comment: Check if [short_open_tag](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag) option is enabled and disable it. Or do what that page says to bypass it.

Comment: @Quentin this question is not a duplicate of that question, as this concerns the inclusion of XML on a PHP page, and that question is the other way around. Also, I tried the solution for that question, and does not resolve my issue.

Comment: @Tijmen — I can't see any way to interpret your question that doesn't boil down to "I have a .php file with `<?xml` in it and the `<?` is triggering PHP mode". That makes it a duplicate. If the solution there didn't fix the problem then show a more complete [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most likely an issue caused by shorthand tags being enabled on your server.
If you have access to your php.ini file; Remove `short_open_tag=On` from your php.ini file.

However, you can also do this in .htaccess by adding the following line:
`php_value short_open_tag 0`

If you have a lot of code on your server using shorthand, it'll break, so opting for a .htaccess solution where you can limit it to 1 location may be a better option for you.

Another solution ( taken from the duplicate ) would be to change your javascript code to:

```
var data = "<?='<'?>?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>" + 
'<request><reference>' + formfield1 + '</reference>
<location>' + formfield2   + '</location>
//etc
```

You'll also need to do the same to the closing `?>`

Comment: I don't have access to the PHP.ini file (although I do have access to the person who does), and this server uses NGINX which does not have .htaccess. In addition, this site runs under Wordpress. I might be mistaken, but I was under the impression Wordpress requires short tags to be enabled, so wouldn't this solution break my site entirely?

Comment: The standard coding practise is to not use shorthand tags so I would be very suprised if it's being used in wordpress. The thread that marked this one as a duplicate has a good bypass however involving splitting the `<` away from `?xml`

Comment: Thanks for trying, I'll see if any other solutions are offered, otherwise I will try yours.

Comment: I edited my answer to include a split of `<` and `xml`

Comment: I used your answer as a starting point. I ended up breaking the variable apart to the extreme, but now it's working. Thanks! I'll update my question in case someone finds this thread in the future.